# Watch iPhone videos without transfer to Mac

Tags: iphone, video, music, data-transfer, shazam

How can I watch the videos I recorded on my iPhone without first transferring them to my drive, so that I can Shazam the music in them? I have no free disk space and iFunbox is not a great file explorer. To my knowledge, Shazam does not have a desktop version.

What software will let me watch the videos on my iPhone without resorting to the unusable Photos or Image Capture apps?

Comment: Can't you just use Shazam on the phone to listen to videos playing on the Mac? Also, you might get better answers if you focus your question on what you actually want to achieve and not on the constraints you face.

Comment: In addition, some more explanations about your setup might help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, [Shazam for Mac](https://itunes.apple.com/app/shazam/id897118787) (opens Mac App Store) exists.

Features:

> - Operates magically in the background, ready to name that tune at a moment’s notice.
> - Instant, seamless access to all the music that makes up the world around you.
> - One-click access to lyrics, music videos or to listen on Apple Music.
> - Discover like never before, share like always.